# How to better identify the source of exceptions in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working to write an AngularJS SPA. As I'm a bit new to the framework, I keep on having errors when I run through the app and I see that an exception is thrown in the console. However, I largely find these exceptions to be remarkably useless as they don't tell me where the problem is occurring (e.g. file, type of provider or line number). The Chrome console simply shows me over to line 36 of the angular.js file which doesn't help.

If I've made changes to a number of files since the last run through, it becomes a haystack hunt looking for what exactly Angular is getting happy about.

For example, I seem to have referenced the dependency for $rootScope somewhere, but who knows where exactly it is. Here's my current exception URL: [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=home&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.15%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524rootScope%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Err](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/%24injector/modulerr?p0=home&p1=Error%3a%20%5B%24injector%3aunpr%5D%20http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/%24injector/unpr?p0=%2524rootScope%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Err)

Am I doing this wrong? Is there some tool I don't know about that simplifies this whole javascript development process substantially?

Edit: Per the answer I received, I worked out the problem was me referring to another service incorrectly and had nothing to do with $rootScope. And I only figured this out after commenting out $rootScope across the entire application and finally getting an error that said the name of my function in it. Then I took that and looked up every instance of it in my logic until I found the problem.

But this seems wildly inefficient. Surely there's a better way than commenting out large chunks of the program simply to cut down on all the places where the problem might be lurking?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to post some code.  Maybe drop it into a Plunker or JSFiddle so folks can help you out.

As for find errors in javascript, I am new to working with it and Angular.  The approach I have been using while learning is to break things down to something that is working. Then slowly start un-commenting until I find what was making Angular un-happy. Learn why, and proceed.

There is also a site called: http://www.jslint.com that I have found to be helpful in getting javascript right. Though word of warning, it is very particular.